# How to find matching objects when comparing two arrays of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have two arrays of objects.

One array contains objects representing users. These objects have two properties, `partido` and `categoria`.

A second array contains objects representing collections. These objects may have many properties, which also include the properties `partido` and `categoria`.

### Question 1

My first question is how do I find objects in the second array that  are matches. The object in the second array should be a match if it contains the same properties and values as one of the objects from the first array. The other properties can have any value, so long as `partido` and `categoria` match.

The result should be an array containing the matching objects from the second array.

#### Array 1

```
const userData = [
  { partido: 'Partido 8', categoria: '2'},
  { partido: 'Partido 13', categoria: '3' }
];
```

#### Array 2

```
collectionData = [
  {
    partido: 'Partido 8',
    Equipo_Local: 'Argentina',
    Equipo_Visitante: 'Arabia SaudÃ­',
    categoria_1: '1',
    categoria: '2',
    Categoria_3: 'No disponible',
  },
  {
    partido: 'Partido 24',
    Equipo_Local: 'Argentina',
    Equipo_Visitante: 'MÃ©xico',
    Categoria_1: 'Disponible',
    categoria: '2',
    Categoria_3: 'disponible',
  },
  {
    partido: 'Partido 13',
    Equipo_Local: 'Polonia',
    Equipo_Visitante: 'Argentina',
    Categoria_1: 'No disponible',
    Categoria_2: 'No disponible',
    categoria: '3',
  },
];
```

So far I've attempted something like:

```
function compararObjetos(userData, collectionData) {
  for (let index = 0; index < userData.length; index++) {
    const element = userData[index];
    let keys = Object.keys(element);
    return collectionData.filter(function(obj) {
      for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
        if(!obj.hasOwnProperty(keys[i]) || obj[keys[i]] !== element[keys[i]]) {
          return false;
        }
      }
      return true;
    })
  }
}
```

### Question 2

My follow-up question is that I would like to perform the same comparison to check for matches, but instead of getting matches from the second array, get a list of objects from the first array that resulted in a match. This assumes we can have many objects in our first array and some may not result in matches. We just want to return the objects that have matches. What is a good way to do this?

### Question 3

Finally, rather than check for a match based on all the properties of the objects in the first array, what if we only need to check that certain properties match?

For instance, the objects can have many other properties but in our case there are 4 specific keys/names that need to have matching values for between the two objects in order to be considered a match.

In my example, I need to return a list of objects from the first array `userData` that resulted in matches for the keys `partido`, `categoria_1`, `categoria_2` and `categoria_3`.

Here is what I tried so far. I think this should be returning matches for `Tania` and `Vania`, but I cannot figure out why it's still returning an empty array:

```js
const userData = [
    { user_name: "Tania", email: "user-1@gmail.com", partido: "8", categoria_1: "1", categoria_2: "2", categoria_3: null },
    { user_name: "Jean", email: "user-2@gmail.com", partido: "12", categoria_1: "1", categoria_2: null, categoria_3: "3" },
    { user_name: "Tom", email: "user-3@gmail.com", partido: "39", categoria_1: "1", categoria_2: null, categoria_3: null },
    { user_name: "Vania", email: "user-4@gmail.com", partido: "13", categoria_1: null, categoria_2: null, categoria_3: "3" }
  ],
  collectionData = [
    {
      partido: "8",
      Equipo_Local: "Argentina",
      Equipo_Visitante: "Arabia SaudÃ­",
      categoria_1: "1",
      categoria_2: "No",
      categoria_3: "No"
    },
    {
      partido: "24",
      Equipo_Local: "Argentina",
      Equipo_Visitante: "MÃ©xico",
      categoria_1: "No",
      categoria_2: "2",
      categoria_3: "No"
    },
    {
      partido: "13",
      Equipo_Local: "Polonia",
      Equipo_Visitante: "Argentina",
      categoria_1: "No",
      categoria_2: "No",
      categoria_3: "3"
    }
  ];

function compareObjects(first, second) {
  let matches = [];

  second.forEach((possibleMatch) => {
    const pickedCollection = (({ partido, categoria_1, categoria_2, categoria_3 }) => ({ partido, categoria_1, categoria_2, categoria_3 }))(possibleMatch);
  first.forEach((userData) => {
  
      const isMatch = Object.keys(userData).every((key) => {

        return userData[key] === pickedCollection[key];

      });

      if (isMatch && !matches.find((match) => match === userData)) {
        matches.push(userData);
      }
    });
  });

  return matches;
}

console.log(compareObjects(userData, collectionData));
```

Comment: Any of your `return` do an exit function   (and ignore loop continuation)

Answer (score 1):

as I told you in my first comment here:
Any of your `return` do an **exit** function (and ignore loop continuation)

you can simply do :
*(same answer with code optimization)*
use also [Array.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) method

```js
function compararObjetos(userData, collectionData)
  {
  let userCollection = []     // future result

  if (userData.length === 0)   // if userData array is empty
    return userCollection     // return an empty array, and exit function

  collectionData.forEach( cRow =>  // roll over each collectionData rows
    {                             // ...and give them 'cRow' as a locale name
    if (userData.some( uRow =>     // roll over each userData rows and
      Object                      // check if one of them is corresponding       
      .keys( uRow )              // get keys names on this userData row
      .reduce( (t,k) => t && (uRow[k]===cRow[k]), true)  // classic reduce...       
      ))                                                // ...(read forward)
      userCollection.push({...cRow}); // true?-> add a cRow copy in response
    })
  return userCollection
  }

// testing...
const
  dataUser = 
    [ { partido: 'Partido 8',  categoria: '2' } 
    , { partido: 'Partido 13', categoria: '3' } 
    ] 
, dataCollection = 
    [ { partido          : 'Partido 8'
      , Equipo_Local     : 'Argentina'
      , Equipo_Visitante : 'Arabia SaudÃ­'
      , categoria_1      : '1'
      , categoria        : '2'
      , Categoria_3      : 'No disponible'
      } 
    , { partido          : 'Partido 24'
      , Equipo_Local     : 'Argentina'
      , Equipo_Visitante : 'MÃ©xico'
      , Categoria_1      : 'Disponible'
      , categoria        : '2'
      , Categoria_3      : 'disponible'
      } 
    , { partido          : 'Partido 13'
      , Equipo_Local     : 'Polonia'
      , Equipo_Visitante : 'Argentina'
      , Categoria_1      : 'No disponible'
      , Categoria_2      : 'No disponible'
      , categoria        : '3'
      } 
    ]
 
console.log( compararObjetos(dataUser, dataCollection) )
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important;top: 0;}
.as-console-row::after {display: none !important;}
```

// previous first answer

```js
function compararObjetos(userData, collectionData)
  {
  let userCollection = []            // future result

  userData.forEach (uRow =>          // roll over each userData rows
    {
    let keys = Object.keys( uRow )   // get keys names on this row
    collectionData.forEach( cRow =>  // roll over each collectionData rows 
      {
      if (keys.reduce((t,k)=> t && (uRow[k]===cRow[k]),true)) // classic reduce usage (read forward)
        userCollection.push({...cRow})                       // add a copy collectionData row to response
      })
    })
  return userCollection
  }

const
  dataUser = 
    [ { partido: 'Partido 8',  categoria: '2' } 
    , { partido: 'Partido 13', categoria: '3' } 
    ] 
, dataCollection = 
    [ { partido          : 'Partido 8'
      , Equipo_Local     : 'Argentina'
      , Equipo_Visitante : 'Arabia SaudÃ­'
      , categoria_1      : '1'
      , categoria        : '2'
      , Categoria_3      : 'No disponible'
      } 
    , { partido          : 'Partido 24'
      , Equipo_Local     : 'Argentina'
      , Equipo_Visitante : 'MÃ©xico'
      , Categoria_1      : 'Disponible'
      , categoria        : '2'
      , Categoria_3      : 'disponible'
      } 
    , { partido          : 'Partido 13'
      , Equipo_Local     : 'Polonia'
      , Equipo_Visitante : 'Argentina'
      , Categoria_1      : 'No disponible'
      , Categoria_2      : 'No disponible'
      , categoria        : '3'
      } 
    ]
 
console.log( compararObjetos(dataUser, dataCollection) )
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important;top: 0;}
.as-console-row::after {display: none !important;}
```

This code work also in this case:

```
const dataUser = 
    [ { Equipo_Visitante : 'MÃ©xico' } 
    , { partido: 'Partido 13', categoria: '3' } 
    ]
```

---

---

**explanations on**:

```
keys.reduce((t,k)=> t && (uRow[k]===cRow[k]),true)
```

As you can imagine this [Array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) method will return `true` or `false`

for the first row the `keys` values are `keys[0]='partido'` and `keys[1]='categoria'`

that's mean we need to perform this test:

```
(uRow['partido']===cRow['partido'] && uRow['categoria']===cRow['categoria'])
```

so it is:

```
(uRow[keys[0]]===cRow[keys[0]] && uRow[keys[1]]===cRow[keys[1]])
```

as the count of keys elements is unknown this test is done as follows:

```
let t = true   // t is test initial value
for (let k of keys)
  t = t && (uRow[k]===cRow[k])
return t
```

which is simply written in an `Array.reduce()` method:

```
keys.reduce((t,k)=> t && (uRow[k]===cRow[k]),true)
```

otherwise you can also change this test to check that there is at least one matching value:

```
keys.reduce((t,k)=> t || (uRow[k]===cRow[k]),false)
```

Comment: Not sure how you can say the OP's code is convoluted and unpleasant to read, and then write a statement like this: `if (keys.reduce((t,k)=> t && (uRow[k]===cRow[k]),true))`

Comment: Also I'm not sure the output is correct. I think it's supposed to give all matches for the first element in userData that contains matches in collectionData - not all matches for all elements in userData.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, and sorry about not use indentation, I just copy and paste my code. @Mister Jojo 's solution is exactly what I'm looking for, but I wont like just copy and paste, could you please clarify line by line the function of the first example.

Comment: @OmarGiancarlo Ok, I will do that, but first and second example use exactly the same code...

Comment: @OmarGiancarlo I added some explanations, and an optimized answer witch go faster

Comment: @OmarGiancarlo there is a `tidy` button in SO snippet witch do automatic indentation.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I'd do it. This seems a bit more succinct and declarative to me. An explanation is included below the solution.

### Solution

Here is the function:

```
function compareObjects(first, second) {
  let matches = [];

  second.forEach((possibleMatch) => {
    first.forEach((obj) => {
      const isMatch = Object.keys(obj).every((key) => {
        return obj[key] === possibleMatch[key];
      });
      if (isMatch && !matches.find((match) => match === possibleMatch)) {
        matches.push(possibleMatch);
      }
    });
  });

  return matches;
}
```

And here is a full working example with your data set:

```
const userData = [
    { partido: "Partido 8", categoria: "2" },
    // { categoria_1: "1", Equipo_Local: "Argentina" },
    // { categoria_1: "1", Equipo_Local: "Palonia" },
    { partido: "Partido 13", categoria: "3" }
  ],
  collectionData = [
    {
      partido: "Partido 8",
      Equipo_Local: "Argentina",
      Equipo_Visitante: "Arabia SaudÃ­",
      categoria_1: "1",
      categoria: "2",
      Categoria_3: "No disponible"
    },
    // {
    //   partido: "Partido 8",
    //   Equipo_Local: "Palonia",
    //   Equipo_Visitante: "Argentina",
    //   categoria_1: "1",
    //   categoria: "2",
    //   Categoria_3: "No disponible"
    // },
    {
      partido: "Partido 24",
      Equipo_Local: "Argentina",
      Equipo_Visitante: "MÃ©xico",
      Categoria_1: "Disponible",
      categoria: "2",
      Categoria_3: "disponible"
    },
    {
      partido: "Partido 13",
      Equipo_Local: "Polonia",
      Equipo_Visitante: "Argentina",
      Categoria_1: "No disponible",
      Categoria_2: "No disponible",
      categoria: "3"
    }
  ];

/**
 *
 * @param {Object[]} first
 * @param {Object[]} second
 *
 * A function that takes in two arrays of objects and
 * returns an array of matching objects from the second
 * array, where a match is defined as an object from the
 * second array which, when compared against the objects
 * in first array, contains the same entries (the same key/value pairs
 * are present in the object in the second array) as at least
 * one of the objects.
 *
 */
function compareObjects(first, second) {
  let matches = [];

  second.forEach((possibleMatch) => {
    first.forEach((obj) => {
      const isMatch = Object.keys(obj).every((key) => {
        return obj[key] === possibleMatch[key];
      });
      if (isMatch && !matches.find((match) => match === possibleMatch)) {
        matches.push(possibleMatch);
      }
    });
  });

  return matches;
}

console.log(compareObjects(userData, collectionData));
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/get-matches-two-arrays-of-objects-59wcoi

### Explanation

We start by looping over the thing we want to return, the collections. For each collection, we loop over all the users, and when comparing against each user, we check if *every* entry in the user object is present in the collection.

If it's a new match, we add it.

I've generalized the solution to return matches from the `second` arg comparing against the `first` so it can be more useful to others.

I've also commented out additional objects supplied in the arguments to illustrate the line of inquiry in my reply about defining assumptions. This relates to why I included a condition to check for previous matches. You can simply drop that bit if needed.

#### [Edited to include latest questions from OP]

#### Get Objects From First Array That Resulted in a Match

To return objects from the first array that resulted in matches, rather than the matches found in the second, you could do this several ways.

We could move the first array to the outer loop from our first solution. Then, we still make the same comparison to check for matches, but now we push the matching object from the first array rather than the second.

https://codesandbox.io/s/get-first-matches-two-arrays-of-objects-0bovhw

```
const userData = [
    { partido: "Partido 8", categoria: "2" },
    { partido: "Partido 13", categoria: "3" },
    // these won't be matches
    { categoria_1: "28", Equipo_Local: "Argentina" },
    { categoria_1: "1", Equipo_Local: "Palonia" }
  ],
  collectionData = [
    {
      partido: "Partido 8",
      Equipo_Local: "Argentina",
      Equipo_Visitante: "Arabia SaudÃ­",
      categoria_1: "1",
      categoria: "2",
      Categoria_3: "No disponible"
    },
    {
      partido: "Partido 24",
      Equipo_Local: "Argentina",
      Equipo_Visitante: "MÃ©xico",
      Categoria_1: "Disponible",
      categoria: "2",
      Categoria_3: "disponible"
    },
    {
      partido: "Partido 13",
      Equipo_Local: "Polonia",
      Equipo_Visitante: "Argentina",
      Categoria_1: "No disponible",
      Categoria_2: "No disponible",
      categoria: "3"
    }
  ];

/**
 *
 * @param {Object[]} first
 * @param {Object[]} second
 *
 * A function that takes in two arrays of objects and
 * returns an array of matching objects from the first
 * array, where a match is defined as an object from the
 * first array whose entries (key/value pairs), when
 * compared against the objects in second array, are all
 * present in at least one of objects in the second array.
 */
function getFirstMatches(first, second) {
  let matches = [];

  first.forEach((possibleMatch) => {
    second.forEach((obj) => {
      const isMatch = Object.keys(possibleMatch).every((key) => {
        return obj[key] === possibleMatch[key];
      });
      if (isMatch && !matches.find((match) => match === possibleMatch)) {
        matches.push(possibleMatch);
      }
    });
  });

  return matches;
}

console.log(getFirstMatches(userData, collectionData));
```

#### Get Objects From First Array That Resulted in a Match Based On Only Specific Keys

To get matches based on only specific keys you could just check against every one of those keys rather than all the keys of the object.

https://codesandbox.io/s/matches-array-of-objects-specific-keys-16k7gg

```
const userData = [
    {
      user_name: "Tania",
      email: "user-1@gmail.com",
      partido: "8",
      categoria_1: "1",
      categoria_2: "2",
      categoria_3: "No"
    },
    {
      user_name: "Jean",
      email: "user-2@gmail.com",
      partido: "12",
      categoria_1: "1",
      categoria_2: "No",
      categoria_3: "3"
    },
    {
      user_name: "Tom",
      email: "user-3@gmail.com",
      partido: "39",
      categoria_1: "1",
      categoria_2: "No",
      categoria_3: "No"
    },
    {
      user_name: "Vania",
      email: "user-4@gmail.com",
      partido: "13",
      categoria_1: "No",
      categoria_2: "No",
      categoria_3: "3"
    }
  ],
  collectionData = [
    {
      partido: "8",
      Equipo_Local: "Argentina",
      Equipo_Visitante: "Arabia SaudÃ­",
      categoria_1: "1",
      categoria_2: "No",
      categoria_3: "No"
    },
    {
      partido: "24",
      Equipo_Local: "Argentina",
      Equipo_Visitante: "MÃ©xico",
      categoria_1: "No",
      categoria_2: "2",
      categoria_3: "No"
    },
    {
      partido: "13",
      Equipo_Local: "Polonia",
      Equipo_Visitante: "Argentina",
      categoria_1: "No",
      categoria_2: "No",
      categoria_3: "3"
    }
  ];

const checkedKeys = ["partido", "categoria_1", "categoria_2", "categoria_3"];

/**
*
* @param {Object[]} first
* @param {Object[]} second
*
* A function that takes in two arrays of objects and
* a specific set of keys to check against and returns 
* an array of matching objects from the first
* array, where a match is defined as an object from the
* first array whose entries for the specified keys match
* those in at least one object the second array.
*/
function getFirstMatches(first, second, checkedKeys) {
  let matches = [];

  first.forEach((possibleMatch) => {
    second.forEach((obj) => {
      const isMatch = checkedKeys.every((key) => {
        return obj[key] === possibleMatch[key];
      });
      if (isMatch && !matches.find((match) => match === possibleMatch)) {
        matches.push(possibleMatch);
      }
    });
  });

  return matches;
}

console.log(getFirstMatches(userData, collectionData, checkedKeys));
```

Comment: Thanks, but the function return three object, that is not possible, there is two objects in userData array. The second returned object not match with any userData objects.

Comment: Okay, that's a quick fix. We can use `every()` to check each collection against _all_ the key value pairs for the current user object. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: It does help to be very explicit about how you define a match. The term _match_ is used a bit loosely in the question but never explicitly defined. It’s also not assumed that there should be a 1:1 or 1:many relationship between user and collection. In any case, hopefully this satisfies the logic you require. Let me know if you have any more questions or if I can be of any further help.

Comment: Have you given my updated solution a try? Did I capture the logic you require? Hopefully my comments and questions made sense.

Comment: sorry for the delay to answer, yes! I try your solution and work perfectly, I have  my last question, I know this question was not specified in the main question, the but the need emerged. how can return user seleccion object that match with? I mean instead of return the matched collection data, return the object of user data matched. Thanks!

Comment: when I say the need emerged, I want to say that maybe I'm going to add extra data in the user object, maybe, name, phone, email, and use that data when have a match.

Comment: Based on the information you've provided, I can only assume you are asking for something like this: [https://codesandbox.io/s/get-first-matches-two-arrays-of-objects-0bovhw](https://codesandbox.io/s/get-first-matches-two-arrays-of-objects-0bovhw). This solution uses the very same logic for determining matches between the two arrays, but returns _objects from the first array_ that resulted in a match rather than the second.

Comment: Let me know if this addresses your question, and I'll incorporate it into my answer. Also, if my answer helped you solve your original question, feel free to mark it as an accepted/useful answer :)

Comment: Did you have a look at [https://codesandbox.io/s/get-first-matches-two-arrays-of-objects-0bovhw](https://codesandbox.io/s/get-first-matches-two-arrays-of-objects-0bovhw)? Hope this captured your additional question. If my solution addressed your original question, please feel free to accept my answer in order to let others know what worked for you.

Comment: Stuck again in a new proyect only with with a little variation in the original question, @abgregs your code works fine but if I insert extra data in the userData array, it doesn't work, What I try to say for example if I add inside of the userData array more objects like this { user_name: "Tania", email: "user-1@gmail.com", partido: "8", categoria_1: "1", categoria_2: "2", categoria_3: null } but the keys that I need to find matchs are partido, categoria_1, categoria_2 and categoria_3 in collectionData to return the object where the matched keys were found it. Any idea it very apreciate

Comment: Do not edit the original question. Just ask a new one. Also, `null` and `"No"` aren't the same: https://codesandbox.io/s/matches-array-of-objects-specific-keys-16k7gg

Comment: First thanks for answer. Ok I'm not going to edit anymore my originals question. Sorry. Yes, null and "No" are not the same, null come from databse, and "No" come from a json file. I see your sandbox, but your function return an array with only one object(let's say Vania), and it supposed to return in this case two objects that contain user_name (vania and Tania) because the object what contain user_name Tania also contain, partido: "8", categoria_1: "1",  That match with the keys, in one object inside the collectionData array.

Comment: Not sure, but I think that I found the problem and maybe need change the default values to the specifics keys that come from data base in this case userData[] and collectionData[]. For example remove null and put "0" like default value, also I do the same with collectionData[] remove the string "No" and put "0" like defualt value

Comment: If you want matches based on the 4 keys you listed, then `Tania` is _not_ a match because `categoria_2`of `2` does not equal value of`"No"` found in the only potential match in collection data. Only `Vania` is a match.

Comment: Yes, your data should be of the same type if possible (ex. only allow `true/false` if a boolean rather than `"No"` and `null`) in order ensure you can reliably compare the values.

Comment: Thanks! I apreciate your help. Your solution works partially. Because only works if the 4 keys that I listed matches exactly with values. I changed the default values types and still not get matches. what I try to say for example is the user's values changes dynamically, also `collectionData` values change dynamically, that's why is necesary find matches. For example maybe Vania selection's have `partido: "8"` and `categoria_3: "3"` that match in `collectionData` and `categoria_1` and `categoria_2` not match.

Comment: Sure, no problem. I'm happy to take a look if you can provide a more detailed example in a new question and tag me in a comment. This is an extensive discussion and you have not selected an answer to your original question(s), so I'll suggest an edit to this question and that you ask a brand new question. In the new question, I would recommend you provide an example of what you mean by only needing some properties to count for a match versus the 4 you listed. How and when do we, as the developer, know? Is it 2? Which 2? Is it 4? There isn't enough information to know what you mean.